# How to delete all commits in Bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket

I want to revert all my changes in a repository, so is it possible to delete all commits in Bitbucket? If so, how?

Comment: Create a new repo (discard old one, if not required). Isn't that sufficient?

Answer (score 6):

I have no idea why you'd want to do something like this, but..

One way to do it would be to reset to your initial commit:

```
git reset --hard (find the sha1 of your first commit)
```

and then force push:

```
git push -f
```

You're pretty much rewriting the entire history of whatever branch you're pushing to. Why not just create a new repository?

Comment: If your initial commit is say for example a 3GB one, you still have that monster in the closet and this does not remove it.

Answer (score 1):

`git reset --hard <commit>`

Read more here:
https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorial/undoing-changes#!reset