# Remove a file completely

Tags: git, bitbucket

I was testing how to work with git/bitbucket. And I uploaded a file that I should not. Now I removed it, but it still able to be seen in history. How may I delete it completely ?

Comment: Do you mean some kind of history visible on the Bitbucket web user interface?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the answer you are looking for is covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3458685/how-can-i-completely-remove-a-file-from-a-git-repository?lq=1)

> The tool you want is git filter-branch. Its usage is described here,
>   but basically:
>
> ```
> $ git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -f my_file' HEAD will remove
> "my_file" from every commit.
> ```
>
> Notice that this rewrites every commit, so if you push into a remote
>   repository, you have to (a) force the update, and (b) everyone else
>   who pulled from you will now have duplicate commits (since you rewrote
>   the history), as described on the [git rebase man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#_recovering_from_upstream_rebase).

Answer (score -1):

```
git reset --hard (find the sha1 of your first commit)
```

and then force push:

```
git push -f
```

I'm pretty much rewriting the entire history of whatever branch you're pushing to.

source [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23186005/2054434)

Comment: With this command you will also loose all the commits after the `sha1` you have found. I think this not what you want to achieve. Instead, stick to the solution provided by @Christian